# How to setup code skeleton for an iphone application

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, architecture, skeleton-code

I want to setup code skeleton for an iPhone application proper standardize and in proper formatted folder structure, but i am not getting any reference link, can anyone please guide how to make an standard architecture of an iPhone application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Its upto you how you like to put files in which folder but main thing if you are adding folders locally + phisically in your project its good practice to avoid special characters & space to folder name.[image]

Answer (score 1):

The below references can give you a start for structuring your code and also provide standard app architecture

*Follow MVC Architecture*
Reference : https://www.raywenderlich.com/132662/mvc-in-ios-a-modern-approach

*Use Design Patterns*
Reference : https://www.raywenderlich.com/86477/introducing-ios-design-patterns-in-swift-part-1